# Problem of querying the Hyperledger Historian

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am developing Hyperledger composer application and I want to get all the transactions related data like transaction type,transaction Id and timestamp to a particular stakeholder who involved in. I created following query to get data from historian.

```
 query getFromHistorian {
     description:"get user transactions"
     statement:
         SELECT org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord
         WHERE (participantInvoking == _$stakeholder)
 }
```

But when I execute this query by giving a stakeholder id using REST API it serve empty response body. How can I fix it and did I do the right thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that the current participant have permissions to READ the historian in the permissons.acl file or the query will always returns empty array.

```
rule ParticipantWhoCanReadHistorian {
  description: "this type of participants can read HistorianRecord to the Historian"
  participant: "the participant name space"
  operation: READ
  resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord"
  action: ALLOW  
}
```

Comment: I already checked It. Following is my access control rule.                                        
rule historianAccess{
 description: " read access to Stakeholders"
 participant:"org.ucsc.agriblockchain.Stakeholder"
 operation: READ
 resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord"
 action: ALLOW
}

Comment: ok let's make sure first that there is no problem in the network by giving the admin access to all resources by issuing the following rule
    rule NetworkControlPermission {
      description:  "give admin ALL access to system resources"
      participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
      operation: ALL
      resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
      action: ALLOW  
    }
or try other participant have access to historian

Comment: It also there. I don't know is it allow to query historian like this way. In their docs they provide another way https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/historian  but i have no idea how to do it they not give proper explanation about the way of doing it. any idea?

Comment: ok make sure that in your WHERE condition while invoking the query that the stakeholder you provide as parameter for the query is of type Relationship provided from namespace: 'org.ucsc.agriblockchain' and type: 'Stakeholder'.

Comment: Thanks for your help. the correct access control rule is ,rule historianRead{
  description: "historian read"
  participant:"org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
  operation: READ
  resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord"
  action: ALLOW

} Now it works.