# How to get history of particular transaction in Hyperledger historian

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am developing Hyperledger composer application.I used a query to obtain historian for a particular stakeholder.That means when I enter specific stakeholder as a input and it gives all the transactions related to that person.the output is seems like below.

```
{

"$class": "org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord",
"transactionId": "0010a094a2d554b37896649f31b827936958038726a86171f80b508a03873f8e",
"transactionType": "org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant",
"transactionInvoked": "resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant#0010a094a2d554b37896649f31b827936958038726a86171f80b508a03873f8e",
"participantInvoking": "resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#admin",
"identityUsed": "resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity#b2875576ddcc5dde2f1b674e22055a43d3ca4d218795edda21e3a7566c904ee8",
"eventsEmitted": [],
"transactionTimestamp": "2018-09-20T06:59:12.271Z"

 }
```

But I want more information than this like kind of participant that were created as mentioned in the transactionType.How can I get those information?

Answer (score 0):

Check This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52352835/problem-of-querying-the-hyperledger-historian/52364674#52364674) and read comments carefully because the return result from querying historian depends on the where condition you provide.